# Почему меняется X2 при изменении X?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = [[5, 8], [14, 47]]
x2 = x.copy()
x[0][0] = 35
print(x)
print(x2)
```

[[35, 8], [14, 47]]

[[35, 8], [14, 47]]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну так может вы хотели вызвать NumPy.copy?

Comment: А нельзя как то скопировать без использования библиотек?

Comment: Потому что вы скопировали только внешний массив, а вложенные массивы остались те же самые. Используйте copy.deepcopy (это не сторонняя библиотека) или типа того

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы все было идеально, обычно применяется `copy.deepcopy`:

```
import copy
x = [[1, 2], [3, [4, 5]]]
x2 = copy.deepcopy(x)
x[0][0] = 179
print(x, x2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и без библиотек. Примерно так:

```
x = [[5, 8], [14, 47]]
x2 = [i.copy() for i in x]
x[0][0] = 35

print(x)
print(x2)
'''
[[35, 8], [14, 47]]
[[5, 8], [14, 47]]
```